# How do we determine a disease's incubation period?

Tags: pathology

There was a suspected case of Ebola in France, which was later dismissed, since the suspect lastly came into contact with a potentially contaminated person more than 21 days before, which is the maximum of Ebola's incubation period.

So, more generally speaking, how does one determine the period of incubation ? How do we know the day a person was contaminated ?

Comment: You need to know the growth dynamics (develop a mathematical infection model) of the concerned pathogen.

Comment: It could be determined empirically, by tracing how much time passed between the sick person coming into contact with another sick person and developing symptoms of their own.